# Check Constraint to Confirm Exactly One is not NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, check-constraints

I have a table with the columns `CompaniesId` and `HotelsId`. I want to write a check constraint that confirms that one of these columns is null and other one is not.

I tried the following expression:

```
(CompaniesId is null) <> (HotelsId is null)
```

When I attempt to save this in the Check Constraints dialog box in SSMS, I get the helpful message:

> Error validating constraint 'CK_CostingLineItemVendors'.

Could someone help me with my syntax?

**EDIT:**

According to the article [IS [NOT] NULL (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx), the result of `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` is `Boolean`. That's why I would assume I could compare these results for equality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

T-SQL does not have a usable boolean type. You can't have an expression that has boolean type and expect to use it like any other expression. All the places in T-SQL where you seemingly can use a boolean expression (like `WHERE`) are hard-coded places in the syntax. (Yes, this is a deficiency without specific reason.)

Simply abuse a bit or an int as a bool:

```
IIF(CompaniesId is null, 1, 0) <> IIF(HotelsId is null, 1, 0)
```

`IIF` is an intrinsic function that can take a condition as the first argument like a `CASE` can. You can't define such a function yourself.

Comment: Obviously, I spend most of my time in languages other than SQL.

Comment: Thumbs up for giving what the OP wanted, but it's really not recommended to perform functions on column in the where clause because of performance issues.

Comment: @Stephan: Valid point, but this *was* the information I was after. I probably will always think in terms of conciseness because I have been using languages that like that for many, many, many years. But perhaps the longer version does make more sense here. (BTW, using `iif`SSMS converts it to a CASE statement.)

Comment: @usr: `IS NULL` is not a function, `ISNULL` is one. Also, T-SQL _does_ have a boolean type and it's returned from [`IS (NOT) NULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx). But it cannot be used in that way.

Comment: This is just semantics. It behaves like a function but has different notation. It might say "Boolean result" in the docs but it's a farce. What good is a type that you can't use? It's effectively not there. It exists merely as a textual statement in the docs.

Comment: @usr: a function cannot make use of an index a predicate like `IS` can. You can use `boolean` but not as datatype for a column or variable but for the `WHERE`. May be nitpicking, just wanted to say that it exists because your first sentence argues the contrary..

Comment: Functions *can* make use of an index if the query processor understands them. IS NULL is a function to the query processor. The specific letters used to denote that function call are irrelevant to the defined mechanics. There was an example of a function that was SARGable but I can't find it right now. Anyway, I clarified the first sentence a bit.

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
   (CompaniesId is null AND HotelsId is not null) 
OR (CompaniesId is not null AND HotelsId is null)
```

Comment: I need to use this on a couple of tables and was looking for a more concise expression. Can you explain why my more concise version won't work?

Comment: @JonathanWood: because it's not a valid syntax. But honestly i'm not sure where it is documented. `IS (NOT)` returns a `BOOLEAN` which cannot be used like in a programming language. It's valid f.e. in a `WHERE`. _"Unlike other SQL Server data types, a Boolean data type cannot be specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot be returned in a result set."_ You can use `<>` or `!=` only with [expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190286.aspx).

Comment: Don't put too much focus on "conciseness". Sure when possible, it is better, but your focus you should be performance and accuracy.  Tim's code will perform both of those well. As far as conciseness, it's not bad either. If you're worried for someone later using it and not knowing what's going on, well then just pop a comment in the code to tell that programmer what your code is doing.