# MySQL Check constraints: only one column is not null

Tags: mysql, database, constraints

This question is similar to [Check Constraint to Confirm Exactly One is not NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039973/check-constraint-to-confirm-exactly-one-is-not-null), but for MySQL and multiple columns, and MySQL supports check since v8.0.16.

For example, I have a "Post" Table and it has three columns which are author_id, manager_id, editor_id. Only one of these three columns should be not null.

How to achieve this in MySQL Check constraints?

Maybe something like

```
not_null_sum = (author_id is not null ? 1 : 0) + (manager_id is not null ? 1 : 0) + (editor_id is not null ? 1 : 0)
not_null_sum should == 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try summing up a boolean expression which checks the total count of null columns:

```
CHECK (author_id IS NULL + manager_id IS NULL + editor_id IS NULL = 1)
```

Comment: Just test it. `CHECK ((author_id IS NOT NULL) + (manager_id IS NOT NULL) + (editor_id IS NOT NULL) = 1)` this works well. Thanks!